# HTML content is adjusting my CSS in an unexpected way

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a React component which is divided into 3 parts to hold 3 different data values - date, title and amount.
The layout looks good and aligned, but when I add a value in the first section (red), it will adjust my CSS is a very strange way which I can not figure out why.
First image shows the component itself, second image shows the component with HTML content inside it.

**Expense.js**

```
  <div className="expense">
  <div className="date">
        <h6>DEMO!</h6>
  </div>
  <div className="title">

  </div>
  <div className="amount">

  </div>
```

**Expense.css**

```
.expense {
    border: 1px darkslategrey solid;
    height: 100px;
    display: flow-root;
}

.date {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: darkred;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
}

.title {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: darkorange;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
}

.amount {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: darkgreen;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you inspected in your browsers dev tools to see who/where is setting the margins in the h6?

Comment: Do you mean “unexpected”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to the three (inline-block) components. The default value for this is `baseline`, which is what you see in your second image.

Actually you don't need to add it three times, but can do it like this:

```
.expense > div {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Full code (converted to plain HTML/CSS):

```css
.expense {
  border: 1px darkslategrey solid;
  height: 100px;
  display: flow-root;
}

.expense>div {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.date {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: darkred;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}

.title {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: darkorange;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
}

.amount {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="expense">
  <div class="date">
    <h6>DEMO!</h6>
  </div><div class="title">

  </div><div class="amount">

  </div>
</div>
```